# Send auto mail (without popping up any window) after "Confirm Order" button pressed in odoo 8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I am using odoo 8. I want to send auto mail (without popping up any window) after "Confirm Order" button pressed in saved Request for Quotation(RfQ).
I have created new module which extends 'purchase.order'

```
class purchase_confirm(osv.osv):

    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    def wkf_confirm_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        ctx = dict(context)
        ctx.update({
            'lang': 'en_US',
            'tz': 'Asia/Dhaka',
            'uid': uid,
            'send_rfq': False,
            'default_model': 'purchase.order',
            'active_model': 'purchase.order',
            'default_res_id': ids[0],
            'default_use_template': bool(template_id),
            'default_template_id': template_id,
            'default_composition_mode': 'comment',
        })

        self.pool.get('mail_compose_message').send_mail(cr, uid, ids, context=ctx)

        return True
```

But it is showing following error when I press the "Confirm Order" button:

```
ValueError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_mail'" while evaluating
u'wkf_confirm_order()'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mail_sent = self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(
    cr,
    self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'base', 'user_root')[1],
    template_id,                        # purchase order model should be selected in email template form
    purchase_order_record.id,           # record id
    force_send=True,
    context=ctx
)
```

Comment: my bad :( . it is showing: ValueError: "'purchase.order' object has no attribute 'env'" while evaluating u'wkf_confirm_order()'

Comment: Sure, because you are using the api v7. I have updated my answer

Comment: Now it is showing: 

Warning!

Sender email is missing or empty after template rendering. Specify one to deliver your message.

Can you please tell me in which template in need to set "From" address? I have multiple template in Technical > Templates. Sorry I am new in Odoo. I am using Odoo-8.

Comment: Well I whink you should put something like this: `${object.partner_id.email}`. The field `template_id` (this is in my answer) is the ID of the template in the `email_template` table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works for me.

```
def wkf_confirm_order(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    obj_id = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    ir_model_data = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'your_module_name', 'your_email_template_xml_id')[1]
    if template_id:
       self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(cr, uid, template_id,obj_id.id, force_send=True, context=context)
    return True
```

Comment: almost there. do you please have any idea what to do for this warning? I am new in odoo. Warning!

Sender email is missing or empty after template rendering. Specify one to deliver your message

Comment: In your Email template under the "Email Configuration" tab there  field called "From", specify a sender mail in that

Comment: I have multiple templates in Technincal > Templates
I am using for template: 

template_id = ir_model_data.get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'purchase', 'email_template_edi_purchase_done')[1]

Can you please tell me, in which template I need to add sender email for 'email_template_edi_purchase_done'